# camera not detected ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, webcam

when I try to use cheese or Skype it's tell me that it didn't find device and i can't find how to make it work it's Integrated webcam and it work on windows so I don't know why it doesn't work on Ubuntu.

I tried few thing i try to check if **uvcvideo** was at the blacklist but it wasn't.
I also tried few things with `/dev/video` but I don't have any of them I even search the folder.

I don't really know what to do. I look stuff up but didn't found up much. any help will be great.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5914 (rev 08)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5917 (rev 07)  
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)  
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)  
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)  
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)  
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)  
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)  
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)  
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller (rev 21)  
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller (rev 21)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)  
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)  
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)  
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)  
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)  
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)   
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: can you show us output of `lspci` and also what laptop do you have please?

Comment: I use asus VivoBook 15 X542UQ-DM273T