# Camera not detected in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, camera

Today I went to participate in a Google Hangout using Chrome browser.  The browser reported "Camera not detected".  This was surprising, as I have used the camera about once every two months for the four-and-a-half years I have owned this machine.  The last time I used the camera was either April 26 or May 31, 2018.  I am quite diligent about applying software updates when prompted to by Ubuntu.

I checked in System Settings but there is no icon for Camera.  Moreover, when I enterd "Camera" and "Camera not detected" in the search pane, nothing came up.  I searched through Chrome's help, where the suggestions came down to "restart your computer."  Restarting did not solve the problem; the camera remained undetected.

Here is my system information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux zareason 4.4.0-128-generic #154-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 14:15:18 UTC 
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

[Another user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015006/camera-not-detected-ubuntu-16-04) posed this question, provided the output of lspci (which I will do here) but got no response.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

Suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Jim Keenan

Comment: I can't comment so I'll post here. What is the output of `lsusb -v` or `ls -ltrh /dev/video*` ? Additionally here is a link to the ubuntu help page about webcams if you haven't already seen it, perhaps something here will be helpful. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting

Comment: When setting up Skype, that program also reported "Device not found" when it came time to check the camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution came from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04): `Fn+<Cam>` which on my machine is `Fn+F6`.  **"[h]itting the web camera function key on the laptop adds/removes the device in hardware as if it has been physically connected/disconnected."**  Once I did that, I got these findings:

```
$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jun 28 21:38 /dev/video0

$ lsmod | ack '^video\b'
video                  40960  2 i915,msi_wmi
```

Thank you very much.

Jim Keenan

Comment: thank youuu so much!

Comment: Exact same, 4 years later, with Pop!OS (based on Ubuntu 22.04) on System76 Gazelle. Except Fn+F10, which persisted across reboots. Thank you!